# Ряд Фурье, сходимость рядов

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте!
Написал программку в Matlab, которая рисует спектр для периодического сигнала и график сходимости этого сигнала. Но по непонятной причине, для некоторых сигналов получается правильный график сходимости, а для некоторых нет, хотя алгоритм один и тот же(см. на фото). Буду очень благодарен, если кто нибудь посоветует как это исправить.

```
syms t k
T=input('Vvedi period T sek. =');
n=input('skolko harmonik nado poschitatj? = ');
s1=input('Opishi s1(t) funkciju = ');
s2=input('Opishi s2(t) funkciju(esli net-pishi 0) = ');
s3=input('Opishi s3(t) funkciju(esli net-pishi 0) = ');
%========================================================================

%=================== пределы интегрирования ==================
a=input('s1(t) funkcija nachinajetsa(moment vremeni): = ');   
b=input('s1(t) funkcija konchajetsa(moment vremeni): = ');
c=input('s2(t) funkcija nachinajetsa(moment vremeni): = ');  
d=input('s2(t) funkcija konchaetsa(moment vremeni): = '); %  
e=input('s3(t) funkcija nachinajetsa(moment vremeni): = ');  
f=input('s3(t) funkcija konchaetsa(moment vremeni): = ');
%========================================================================
Lidzkomponente=(1/T)*int(s1,t,a,b)+(1/T)*int(s2,t,c,d)+(1/T)*int(s3,t,e,f)
%Lidzkomponente - это постоянная составляющая
%========================================================================

%======================= A koef =====================
for i=1:n,
   A(i)=(2/T)*int(s1*cos(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,a,b)+...
       (2/T)*int(s2*cos(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,c,d)+...
       (2/T)*int(s3*cos(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,e,f);
end;
A=double(A)% Rezultātu izvade
%========================================================================

%======================= B koef =====================
for i=1:n,
    B(i)=(2/T)*int(s1*sin(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,a,b)+...
       (2/T)*int(s2*sin(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,c,d)+...
       (2/T)*int(s3*sin(((i*2*pi)/T)*t),t,e,f);
end;
B=double(B)
%========================================================================

%==================== считаем амплитуды гармоник =================
for i=1:n,
    C(i)=sqrt(A(i)^2+B(i)^2);
end;
C=double(C) 
%======================================================================== 

%=========================== спектр ==========================
FigHandle = figure('Position', [170,120, 1350,550]);
subplot(1,2,1);
x=[0,1/T:1/T:i/T];
CC=[Lidzkomponente,C];
stem(x,CC,'LineWidth',2)
set(gca,'xtick', [1/T:1/T:i/T]);
title('Frequency spectrum');xlabel('f,Hz');ylabel('Amplitude'); grid on
%========================================================================

%=========================== считаем фазы =========================
for i=1:n,
    Phase_in_degrees(i)=-atand(B(i)/A(i));
end;
Phase_in_degrees(isnan(Phase_in_degrees))=0 
%=========================================================================

%=========================== фазовый спектр ===============================
subplot(1,2,2)
x=1/T:1/T:i/T;
y=Phase_in_degrees;
stem(x,y,'LineWidth',2); title('Phase spectrum');xlabel('f,Hz');ylabel('\Psi,°')
set(gca,'xtick', [1/T:1/T:i/T]);
grid on
%=========================================================================
% сходимость функции


solis=T/1000; % шаг
tt=0:solis:3*T;% временная ось
Phs_in_pi=deg2rad(Phase_in_degrees);
for i=1:n,
    harm=C(i)*cos(((i*2*pi/T).*tt)+Phs_in_pi(i));
    H{i}=harm;
end,
catH=cat(3,H{:});
Fr=sum(catH,3);
figure(3)
Frr=[Lidzkomponente+Fr];
plot(tt,Frr);grid on;xlabel('t,sec')
ylabel('S(t)')
```

[image: пример использования программы]
[image: Последние 2 графике не верны]

Answer (score 1):

В случаях 3 и 4 у вас, похоже, спектр входного сигнала шире, чем ваше разложение Фурье, вот вам и погрешности. Для проверки, возьмите в 8 раз больше отсчетов и выучите теорему Котельникова.